# How to use $add aggregate in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that stores employees data. This is the document structure for the collection 'employees'.

```
{
    "emp_id" : 3,
    "Employee_Name" : "Farquleet Shadab",
    "Employee_Gender" : "Male",
    "Employee_Salary" : [
        {
            "month_year" : "Jan-2015",
            "salary_paid" : 100

        },
        {
            "month_year" : "Feb-2015",
            "salary_paid" : 100
        }
    ]
},

{
    "emp_id" : 4,
    "Employee_Name" : "John Robert",
    "Employee_Gender" : "Male",
    "Employee_Salary" : [
        {
            "month_year" : "Jan-2015",
            "salary_paid" : 200

        },
        {
            "month_year" : "Feb-2015",
            "salary_paid" : 200
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to write to write a query to find the total salary paid to employees in the month_year = 'Jan-2015'. I am new to Mongodb and have no idea how to write query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$Employee_Salary"},
    {$match: {"Employee_Salary.month_year": "Jan-2015" }},
    {$project: {salary_paid: "$Employee_Salary.salary_paid"}},
    {$group: {_id: null, total_salary_paied_on_jan_2015: {$sum: "$salary_paid"}}}
])
```

this aggregation query will compute total amount of salary paid in Jan 2015 to all employees.

Comment: This query returns nothing..this is what I get in the output                             {
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "total_salary_paied_on_jan_2015" : 0
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}

Comment: did you change the collection name?

Comment: I am sure it is working, is tested on data you provided. Just change to your collection name, and check again the fields.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an aggregation example:

```
db.salary.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$Employee_Salary"
    }
    ,{
        $match:
        {
            "Employee_Salary.month_year" : "Jan-2015"
        }
    }
    ,{
        $group:
        {
            _id:null,
            total: { $sum: "$Employee_Salary.salary_paid" }
        }
    }
])
```

`$unwind` will explode your array, creating distinct documents for each. Then, `$match` will keep only the matching months. Finally, `$group` will add all salary from the docs that left.

Note: `_id` is not necessary, but if you want to know per example how much was salary per month, you'd just have to remove the $match doc, and into `$group` set `_id: "$Employee_Salary.month_year"`.

Comment: This query does not return total salary paid in the month of Jan-2015..............{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "total" : 0
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}

Comment: Hm, that's weird, I've just tested again with the data you provided, and I get good result: "result": [ { "_id": null, "total": 300 } ]. Here you can see the collection and the aggregate: https://gist.github.com/Cog-g/925dcbd07deb409e24c7

Comment: btw, answer from @SergiuZaharie a few seconds after mine should be good too.